# How to change the default Outlook 2010 start folder?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, inbox

When I start Outlook 2010 it opens the Outlook Data File's inbox

[image]

However, I want it to open my own Inbox by default.

How do I change the default Outlook 2010 start folder?

Comment: Here I was thinking of giving this question away for free...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here are the steps:

- Click on File
- Click on Options from the menu.

[image]

- Click on Advanced (left pane).

[image]

- Under Outlook start and exit, click on the Browse button to designate a different folder.
- Select the folder you wish to use.
- Click OK to save the selection.

Comment: Great detailed answer, just what I was looking for. Thank you !